# Is there anyway to simplify this Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that, when a certain card is clicked, its content is displayed on an overlay card. But the way I have it right now is to repetitive:

HTML:

```
        <div class="card c1">
            <img src="max.png" width="65px">
            <div class="text">
                <h3 class="firstName">Owen</h3>
                <h3 class="lastName">Osagiede</h3> 
                <p>[email]</p> 
                <p>[city]</p>
            </div>
        </div>
 
        <div class="card c2">
            <img src="max.png" width="60px">
            <div class="text">
                <h3 class="firstName">Kanye</h3>
                <h3 class="lastName">West</h3> 
                <p>[email]</p> 
                <p>[city]</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card c3">
            <img src="max.png" width="65px">
            <div class="text">
                <h3 class="firstName">Quando</h3>
                <h3 class="lastName">Rondo</h3> 
                <p>[email]</p> 
                <p>[city]</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
      function overlayUser(){
         card[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
           first.innerHTML = card[1].getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHTML;
           last.innerHTML = card[1].getElementsByTagName('h3')[1].innerHTML;

    });
    card[2].addEventListener('click', function(){
        first.innerHTML = card[2].getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHTML;
        last.innerHTML = card[2].getElementsByTagName('h3')[1].innerHTML;
    });
    card[3].addEventListener('click', function(){
        first.innerHTML = card[3].getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHTML;
        last.innerHTML = card[3].getElementsByTagName('h3')[1].innerHTML;
    });
```

I have tried to loop over it with a for loop, but keep getting an error:

```
      `function overlayUser(){
          for (i = 0; i < card.length; i++){
              card[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                first.innerHTML = card[i].getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHTML;
               last.innerHTML = card[i].getElementsByTagName('h3')[1].innerHTML;
               });
           }
        }`
```

Comment: In your first snippet, you start at `card[1]`. But your loop is starting at `i=0`. Are you intending to add a listener to `card[0]` too?

Comment: The answer you've selected as "the" answer has some very poor performing and potentially insecure code in it. See my answer for the better solution.

Comment: both answers are correct and the one you **selected** is good as well. Just use `textConent`  when getting the `h3` text instead of using `innerHTML` - thats all

Comment: @AlwaysHelping The answer by slebetman is most certainly not good. It's very inefficient and opens up a security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a DOM event handler, the current element is `this`. Therefore you can write a single function for all of them:

```
function handleClick () {
    first.innerHTML = this.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHTML;
    last.innerHTML = this.getElementsByTagName('h3')[1].innerHTML;
}

function overlayUser(){
    for (i = 0; i < card.length; i++){
        card[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }
}
```

The `this` API is the original API for finding out which element caused the event. Thus it is very compatible with all browsers.

Alternatively, if you feel uncomfortable mixing the usage of `this` you can also find out the current element from the event object:

```
function handleClick (event) {
    let card = event.target;

    first.innerHTML = card.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHTML;
    last.innerHTML = card.getElementsByTagName('h3')[1].innerHTML;
}
```

The event object is a slightly less ancient API but is compatible with everything from IE8 and above.

Additionaly you can use event bubbling/capturing to even get rid of the for loop. Just install the event on the parent element of all three cards and let `event.target` sort out which card caused the event:

```
parentDiv.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHTML` <-- There is so much wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over all the individual elements that you want to have event handlers and hooking each up, set a single handler on an ancestor element and allow the event to bubble up to that element. Then, when handling it, look at the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), which refers to the actual element that triggered the event. This is called [*event delegation*](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

Also, [do not use `.getElementsByTagName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) in 2020. That is a 25+ year old API that returns a live node list that can dramatically hurt performance, especially since you are only interested in a single element when you use it.

Addtionally, never use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) if you can avoid it. It has security and performance implications. Since you aren't actually working with a string that needs any HTML parsed, you should use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Finally, you should not be using `h3` unless it is to create a sub-section of a pre-existing `h2`. [Headings are meant to divide your document into ordered sections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) and these sections are used by those who rely on assistive technologies to navigate a document. If you are just using the `h3` because of the styling the browser applies to the text, you should instead just use a `p` and then use CSS to style it the way you want.

```js
// Get references to first and last (for this demo)
let first = document.querySelector(".first");
let last = document.querySelector(".last");

// Just handle the click event at the wrapper of all the cards
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", function (event){
   // Then access the content of the card that actaully triggered the event
   first.textContent = event.target.closest(".card").querySelector("h3").textContent;
   last.textContent = event.target.closest(".card").querySelector("h3:nth-child(2)").textContent;
});
```

```css
/* Just for demo */
.results {
  position:sticky;
  left:50%;
  top:0;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="results">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="last"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card c1">
            <img src="max.png" width="65px">
            <div class="text">
                <h3 class="firstName">Owen</h3>
                <h3 class="lastName">Osagiede</h3> 
                <p>[email]</p> 
                <p>[city]</p>
            </div>
        </div>
 
        <div class="card c2">
            <img src="max.png" width="60px">
            <div class="text">
                <h3 class="firstName">Kanye</h3>
                <h3 class="lastName">West</h3> 
                <p>[email]</p> 
                <p>[city]</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card c3">
            <img src="max.png" width="65px">
            <div class="text">
                <h3 class="firstName">Quando</h3>
                <h3 class="lastName">Rondo</h3> 
                <p>[email]</p> 
                <p>[city]</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```